# TFS Default Group Membership for the Project Administrator group

Tags: tfs, tfs-process-template

We have been using TFS 2010 for about 6 months and we have decided to alter the default CMMI v5 Process Template to add default memberships to the TFS security groups.

When creating a new Team Project we want to default the membership of the **Project Administrators** and **Readers** groups with known Active Directory Groups.  We have successfully added the **ourDomain\TechnologyDivision** to the projects **Readers** group.  So all of Technology has read access to all newly created TFS Team Projects.  (We have a rather small technology division so this is not a security issues for us, it may be for others.)

We would also like to add the **ourDomain\ProjectManagementTeam** to the **Project Administrators** Group.  Unfortunately we we have been unsuccessful at this as the process template does not show the **Project Administrators** Group.

We have tried altering the underling xml files by adding the **Project Administrators** group manually, but this also did not work.  When creating a new TFS Project with this template I received an error on creation, my assumption is that it failed when attempting to create the **Project Administrators** group and one already existed.

Has any one had any luck ad altering the default membership of the Project Administrators group?

Here is an image of the default groups that are listed in the process template.

TFS Process Template Permissions -->

[image: http://i.imgur.com/l2ul1.jpg]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this document: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd380669.aspx

It seems that you need to use the $$PROJECTADMINGROUP$$ macro